# Usage of quantifier with an indefinite pronoun

Tags: quantifiers

When an indefinite pronoun is modified by a quantifier, does it always come after indefinite pronoun?

Eg: "Nothing *much* happened today".

Answer (score 1):

### No.

A qualifier can also come before the pronoun, at least in some cases:

> Almost nothing happened today.

According to [this page](https://www.thoughtco.com/qualifier-words-1691707) a qualifier normally precedes the adjective or adveerb being modified, but nothing is said about pronouns in the sequence.